# Giving money to a shul

Tags: sources-mekorot, synagogue, shulchan-aruch, mishnah-berurah, aruch-hashulchan

Someone told me that giving money towards a *shul* in order to enhance and beautify the physical structure of the building is a *mitzvah*.

Is there source for this?

Comment: This question would be more compelling if you would [edit] in indications of why you think it might or might not be. Also, do you mean "*mitzvah*" as in "one of the 613 *mitzvot*," as in "fulfilling a Halachic requirement," or as in "a good deed, according to Judaism"?

Comment: It seems that it is at least performing the mitzvah of tzedaka. There are separate requirements mentioned in O.C. about a town building a *bet k'nesset*. That **might** include a requirement of maintenance as well.